# How does a Faster R-CNN gets trained and how does the Region Proposal Network fits into that?

Tags: machine-learning, python, pytorch, object-detection, faster-rcnn

so a Faster R-CNN consists of 3 parts:
-the Base CNN
-the Region Proposal Network with RoIpooling
-and the classification CNN at the end

So I asked myself if all these three Networks are trained seperatly and get  united at the end. Or if the whole constillation is trained together
(so that the input flows through all three Networks and so does the backpropagation)?

If the sencond is the case, how does the RPN fits into that? Because the output of the RPN with RoI-pooling are multiple smaller regions which then get forwarded one after another to the last CNN for classification and so it's no more a continous united CNN, right?

I would be really happy to get some answers because I somehow can't find any else where, thanks :)